# Replace math symbols with their prettier Unicode alternatives in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, replace

I have a textarea HTML element where users can input math expressions like `2 * 5` or `3^2 - 14` (React app to be specific). I would like to replace symbols/expressions such as `*`, `^2` or `pi` with their prettier Unicode alternatives: `×`, `²`, `π`.

Obviously, the expression parser would need to understand the alternative symbols, but that's easy to do.

The problem is replacing them properly - when you modify the textarea's value via the `String.replace` function, it moves the cursor to the end of its content. While it's possible to do so (see [update textarea value, but keep cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286595/update-textarea-value-but-keep-cursor-position)) it requires a significant amount of code (or at least that's what I can see so far).

Are there any better ways to achieve this goal? I was thinking about modifying the font so that when a user types `*` it will display `×` - this strategy would definitely not work for something like `pi => π` and I'm not sure whether it's even possible. The font I'm using is Menlo.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385936/change-the-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-with-react

Comment: or this: [Rendering user input from dynamically created textarea using MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600130/rendering-user-input-from-dynamically-created-textarea-using-mathjax)